# How to create an CSV file for OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I was reading on Facial Recogntion on OpenCV and it required me to use an CSV file for my project. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I think it is telling me to use Python to write the code. I have no idea of the code and what I want is to get my own image into the CSV file and let it work. How do I do that? I only have a C++ background and I don't know what to do. Can someone please teach me how to make one of those files? I have googled for a long time but no results.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html

Comment: The linked doc is telling you that they provide a python script to generate your csv from your image files. You just run that script in the directory where your images are contained.

Comment: @MichaelJCox it's not really a `C++` nor a `Python` related question, it's really a pure OpenCV question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file here is used to define the learning database for `FaceRecognition`, it's just a list of image files and a corresponding subject id :

```
/path/to/subject1image1.jpg;0
/path/to/subject1image2.jpg;0
/path/to/subject1image3.jpg;0
...
/path/to/subject2image1.jpg;1
/path/to/subject2image2.jpg;1
...
/path/to/subject3image1.jpg;2
...
```

You could do this by hand if you have the time or you could use their python script.

To use the script you just have to respect the file hierarchy `/basepath/<subject>/<image.ext>` then simply run the script with `python` and it will generates the corresponding CSV file.

Comment: How long does it take to do by hand? If the script is easier, how do I use it? Sorry, I have no python background.

Comment: OR, can I just open Text Editor and just copy the "/path/to/image.jpg;0 " to it and shen save it a anyName.cvs file?

Comment: Do you realize you just have to write the image path of your images in a CSV file ? The times depends on how many images you have. And you don't need any python background to use the script, you just have to run it.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but since you're supposed to have a lot of images to feed the learning algorithm, they give you a script to do that automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You clarified it well for me!!!

Comment: can you provide some example please, i am really a beginner in this. for example my images are in folder C:User/shivam/Desktop/opencv/att_faces/s1/1.pgm, so in my csv file i have write the path like this "C:User/shivam/Desktop/opencv/att_faces/s1/1.pgm;0". Please help